# Should I simulate a cors OPTIONS request in sinon.js or how do I test cross domain ajax requests?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain, sinon

I'm creating unit tests for a javascript/jquery libarary I'm working on. I need to make a lot of cross-domain Ajax requests and am trying to fiddle my way through [Sinon.js](http://sinonjs.org/) to try and simulate the following scenario:

- I do an AJAX "PUT" cross-domain request to `x-domain-abc.com/somestorage`
- I'm including custom headers for authentification
- This will trigger a preflight OPTIONS request
- The request should be caught by the fakeServer and responded with some custom headers (the ones I'm hoping my provider to add ;-)
- Afterwards the actual "PUT" is done, also caught by the fakeServer and responded accordingly.

My request looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url + '?_=' + Date.now(),
  type: 'PUT',
  data: document,
  async: true,
  crossdomain: true,
  headers : {
  Authorization: 'Basic ' + Base64.encode(
    priv.user + ':' + priv.pass
    )
  },
  success: function () {
      // do sth
  },
  error: function () {
      // do sth else
  }
});
```

In my test module I'm currently doing this:

```
test ("Put", function(){
  var o = generateTools(this);
  // lib invocation
  o.jio = JIO.newJio({
    "type": "dav",
    "username": "davput",
    "password": "checkpwd",
    "url": "https://ca-davstorage:8080"
  });

  // put non empty document
  o.addFakeServerResponse("PUT", "put1", 201, "HTML RESPONSE");
  o.spy (o, "value", {"ok": true, "id": "put1"},
         "Create = PUT non empty document");
  // the JSON "document" that should be stored
  o.jio.put({"_id": "put1", "title": "myPut1"}, o.f);
  o.clock.tick(5000);
  o.server.respond();
  o.jio.stop();
});
```

`O` includes:

```
generateTools = function (sinon) {
  var o = {};
  o.t = sinon;
  o.server = o.t.sandbox.useFakeServer();
  o.clock = o.t.sandbox.useFakeTimers();
  o.clock.tick(base_tick);
  o.spy = basicSpyFunction;
  o.tick = basicTickFunction;
  ...
  o.addFakeServerResponse = function (method, path, status, response) {
    var url = new RegExp('https:\\/\\/ca-davstorage:8080\\/' + path +
                    '(\\?.*|$)');
    o.server.respondWith(method, url,
      [status, { "Content-Type": 'application/xml' }, response]
    );
  }
  return o;
},
```

**Question:**
Does it make sense to test for OPTIONS/preflight at all, as it is something handled internally by the browser, which I cannot access or influence?

If not, what should I test on a CORS request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your unit tests are exercising your JavaScript code, you shouldn't need to test the CORS preflight response. As you mention, the details of the preflight are handled behind the scenes by the browser. So there is no code to test for handling a preflight.

You really don't need to do any CORS specific testing since the browser handles all those details for you. From the perspective of your JavaScript, a CORS request looks just like a regular XmlHttpRequest. Your fake server should just return an expected response, and your unit tests should check that your code process this response correctly.

Now, if you were in control of the server, it would be important to test the CORS preflight response. If you really want to be complete, you could set up tests to make preflight and regular CORS requests to your provider. However this would be outside the realm of a simple unit test, since it would be making a live request to a remote server.

Comment: ok. Pretty much what I ended up doing. I ran everything on the fakeServer and then (outside qunit) set up a live dummy server to see if everything was working in a live setting, too. Thanks for the answer